# Why does the formula of a parabola in vertex form include $4p$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

The equation for a parabola in vertex form is

$\displaystyle y=a(x-h)^2+k$

whereas in older or more advanced references to conics, the formula is

$\displaystyle 4p(y-k)=(x-h)^2$

now immediately the correlation is obvious:

$\displaystyle y=a(x-h)^2+k$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{a}(y-k)=(x-h)^2$

hence, $\displaystyle 4p = \frac{1}{a}$

the question is simply why? How does $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a}$ become $4p$? In addition, I'm aware that if the directrix is at $y=-p$ and the focus is at $(0,p)$, then the perpendicular distance from the directrix to the focus is $2p$, so obviously $4p$ is therefore twice the distance from the directrix to the focus, but still, why is $4p$ used instead of just $2p$?

Comment: As you also mentioned that the focus is at $(0,p)$ when the vertex is at the origin. Representing the equation in the form of $4p(y-k)=(x-h)^2$ helps in determining the location of focus, equation of directix etc.

Comment: It is in relation with the geometric definition of the parabola as the locus of points quich are equidistant from a given line (called the *directrix*) and a given point outside that straight line (called the *focus* of the parabola). See details on [Wikippedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Definition_of_a_parabola_as_locus_of_points).

Comment: It's worth noting that $4p$ is the length of the latus rectum of the parabola. The latus rectum has value as a special "focal chord" common to all conic sections; perhaps the fact that its length if four-times the distance from focus to vertex was deemed worthy of highlighting.

Comment: In short: the focal length is often a useful parameter for a parabola, so a useful expression for a parabola would have an expression involving the focal length, in much the same way a useful expression for a circle ought to have the radius as a parameter. You could use, say, the length of the latus rectum as a parameter (thus yielding $L(y-k)=(x-h)^2$, where $L=4p$), if you believe the latus rectum length to be more convenient in an application. (To go back to the circle analogy: you can use the diameter instead of the radius, at the cost of an additional factor.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your question is why do we use the formula

$$ 4p(y-k)=(x-h)^2 $$

rather than the formula

$$ 2p(y-k)=(x-h)^2 $$

Certainly, this could be done, but it would replace each $p$ in the following parabolic relationship diagram with the fraction $\dfrac{p}{2}$. This is the only reason I can think of.

Note also that $4p$ also happens to be the length of the **focal chord** (Latin: *latus rectum*).

[image: parabolic relationships]